# Problem restoring Wordpress database

Tags: mariadb, wordpress

Some months ago I created a Wordpress implementation using NGINX and mariadb (on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian Stretch).

This developed some problems (as a result of a failed attempt to install phpmyadmin). I managed to delete most of these although phpmyadmin was still a user, and I could use Wordpress.

I wanted to do a fresh start (keeping the wordpress database) which I backed up using.

```
sudo mysqldump -u root -p wordpress > wordpress.sql
```

I backed up the existing using

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
sudo mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/.mysql
```

I ran the following to reset mariadb, setting root password

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mariadb-server-10.1
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

I created a new empty wordpress database and restored from database backup

```
sudo mysql -Bse "create database wordpress"
pv wordpress.sql | sudo mysql wordpress
```

I restarted with `sudo systemctl start mariadb`

Unfortunately when I try to connect I get an error "Error establishing a database connection"

Can anyone suggest what I may have done wrong?

Comment: Can you connect to the database from the command line?

Comment: You miss the user, who access wordpress database.

Comment: @RomeoNinov thanks - this put me on the right path to solve my problem.

Comment: It seems like you managed to solve the problem, so could you post an answer detailing the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You just **Export** your database backup from Phpmyadmin and then create new setup and **import** that backup, hopefully your problem will be resolve.

Answer (score -2):

your backup has some problem please take a backup again download same version wordpress and then restore the db also update table name according and can use wordpress migrate url generator
https://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-site-url-migration-generator.html

only after this you will be able to use that database

Comment: -1 - Because there is no punctuation used in your answer. Please [edit] your answer to make it more legible. Also, how legitimate is this website that you have linked to?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).